# How to select a row or column of RMatrix in RcppParallel

Tags: r, rcpp, rcppparallel

I need to work with `RcppParallel::RMatrix`. Previously I worked with `Rcpp` only. But now for `RcppParallel` I need a documention Like What `Rcpp` has.

**For Example**

I `Rcpp::NumericMatrix` We can select a row or column with placeholder "`_`" like this:

```
NumericMatrix new = OldMatrix(_,1);
```

But I want to know How Can Do same for `RcppParallel::RMatrix`?

Thank for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RcppParallel is focused on iterators, and it offers the `RMatrix::Column` and `RMatrix::Row` classes that provide iterators for individual columns and rows:

```cpp
Rcpp::NumericMatrix foo = ...;
RcppParallel::RMatrix<double> bar(foo);

RcppParallel::RMatrix<double>::Column column = bar.column(0);
// use any algorithm on column.begin() to column.end()

RcppParallel::RMatrix<double>::Row row = bar.row(0);
// use any algorithm on row.begin() to row.end()
```